# Daylight savings time being added when string is converted to Timestamp in Java

Tags: java, timezone, timestamp, jodatime, dst

My application receives timestamp in string format and we used `parse()` method in SimpleDateFormat class to convert that String to `Timestamp` object. My application is running in America/New_York timezone, so we faced daylight savings time issue for timestamps between March 9th 2.00 to 2.59 am. We fixed this issue by modifying default timezone properties to make sure all the daylight savings fields are reset to zero. But when we created current timestamp object using java.util.Date class after daylight savings has been changed (March 22), it showed up as 1 hour less than the actual current timestamp. This is because of changing the properties of default timezone.

```
public class DateTest {
    static TimeZone defaultTimeZone = TimeZone.getDefault();
    Timestamp timestamp1;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        DateTest dateTest = new DateTest();
        System.out.println("Current date before changing Timezone:" + new java.util.Date());
        //Adds one hour extra to the actual timestamp
        System.out.println("Converted Timestamp with Daylight:" + convertStringToTimestamp("2014030902101900"));
        System.out.println("=====================================================================");
        //Displays as the actual timestamp
        dateTest.setTimestamp1(convertStringToTimestampWithoutDaylight("2014030902101900"));
        System.out.println("Converted Timestamp with Daylight savings:" + dateTest.getTimestamp1());
        //1 hour is reduced compared to current timestamp as Daylight savings time is removed
        System.out.println("Current date after changing Timezone:" + new java.util.Date());
        System.out.println("=====================================================================");
        //Reset back to the original timezone
        TimeZone.setDefault(defaultTimeZone);
        Displays current timestamp
        System.out.println("Current date after Timezone reset:" + new java.util.Date());

        //Adds one hour again
        System.out.println("Converted Timestamp after Timezone reset:" + dateTest.getTimestamp1());
        System.out.println("=====================================================================");
    }
}
```

We are using both current timestamp object and the string to timestamp conversion in our project. I tried with Joda-Time also, but at the end we need Timestamp object when [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) is converted to Timestamp, daylight savings time is being added.

```
   DateTime dateTime = DateTime.now();
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTime(dateTime.toDate());
        System.out.println("Current Timestamp:" + new Timestamp(calendar.getTimeInMillis()));
        LocalDateTime localdateTime = LocalDateTime.parse("2014030902101100", DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyyMMddHHmmssSS"));
        Calendar calendar2 = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar2.setTime(localdateTime.toDate());
        System.out.println("Converted Timestamp:" + new Timestamp(calendar2.getTimeInMillis()));
```

Output:
Current Timestamp:2014-03-22 09:15:09.478

Converted Timestamp:2014-03-09 03:10:11.0

Comment: You should document the format of that date-time string rather than make us guess. And you should document the meaning of that date-time string; is it already New York time, or is it UTC, or what?

Comment: Added the date-time string format conversion. I'll get date-time string as part of my input EDI message, it doesn't sticked to any timezone and i need to insert the same  into database without any changes. Even if input date time string is March 9, 02.00-02.59 AM, it should not add 1 hour, eventhough it is wrong according to US timezone.

Comment: (a) Do you understand that java.util.Date is confusing because it applies your JVM's default time zone when generating a string in its `toString` method yet actually contains no time zone (is UTC)? (b) Perhaps you should provide the source for your `convertStringToTimestamp` method.

Comment: I am guessing that you are working too hard. Joda-Time should be able to handle this simply. But your writing is terribly difficult to understand. Can you rewrite to say, "I have _this_. It means _this_. I want to get to _this_.". For example, perhaps what you mean is… A system gives me a string like this, `2014030902101100` in this format "yyyyMMddHHmmssSS". That string represents a date-time value in UTC (no time zone offset). I want to transform that string into a date-time value adjusted to America/New_York time zone, and then print in ISO 8601 format such as: `2014-03-24T00:59:42-05:00`.

Comment: In the America/New York timezone timestamps between 2am and 2:59:59am on March 9th this year are as invalid as timestamps for March 32nd or February 29th. There is just no representation for them.

Answer (score 1):

In your parallel thread on LinkedIn you stated that you do not know what time zone your timestamps corresponds to. In most cases this is bad. But if this is indeed the situation you are in, you are free to treat them as timestamps in any timezone you choose. If you don't know whether the timezone to which your timestamps correspond has daylight savings and if does, what rules they follow, your safest choice is to consider them belonging to a time zone that doesn't have daylight savings. I would suggest using UTC. So, before parsing or formating a timestamp you need to set the timezone of the SimpleDateFormat to UTC:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Date date = parseTimestamp("2014030902101100");
    System.out.println("Parsed date: " + formatDate(date));
    date = parseTimestamp("2014032202101100");
    System.out.println("Parsed date: " + formatDate(date));
}

private static Date parseTimestamp(String timestamp) throws ParseException {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmssSS");
    sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    Date date = sdf.parse(timestamp);
    return date;
}

private static String formatDate(Date date) {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SS z");
    sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    return sdf.format(date);
}
```

The output is:

```
Parsed date: 2014-03-09 02:10:11.00 UTC
Parsed date: 2014-03-22 02:10:11.00 UTC
```

Comment: Yeah, actually we will get timestamp as a string in EDI message and we don't know exactly which part of North america it corresponds to :(. If we use above approach UTC time will be converted to the EST format while parsing string which reduces 5 hrs from the actual time. I need to insert the same timestamp which i get in input to DB without affecting daylight savings time, but when i create the new Date object it should return the current date with daylight savings time. I know these two statements are quite contradictory, but my requirement is like this. Please help me out to resolve it.

Comment: As I mentioned earlier, in time zones with the daylight savings some timestamps are as invalid as timestamps for February 29th this year or March 32nd any year. If you want to be able to represent invalid timestamps, you have to represent them and to store them as strings.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to parse the string with SimpleDateFormat,
something like

```
SimpleDateFormat sd  = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmssSSz");
Date date = sd.parse("2014030902101100GMT-05:00");
```

and for the z (timezone) parameter you could add GMT-05:00 (New York offset from GMT/UTC) to the timestamp string that you have at hand.
After this you can convert to what ever you would like.

simpledateforamt.parse will give you date (java.util.date). 
Convesion from date to Timestamp is straight forward.

```
long ms = date.getTime();
Timestamp t =  new Timestamp(ms);
```

Comment: But using this approach 1 hour of DST is added to the actual timestamp string and output is printed as 'Sun Mar 09 03:10:11 EDT 2014'

Comment: Well as you said, Mar 09 2014 was the day when the time changed (one our was added). So 2 became 3. I do not see problem here why you think that this is a problem. But yes now I noticed that for dates that are after 2am Mar 09 you should use **GMT-04:00 or EDT**, since that is the DST for New York. You can try to use this `TimeZone.getDefault().inDaylightTime(new Date());`. or `TimeZone.getTimeZone("US/Eastern").inDaylightTime(new Date());`. So this way you will check is it into daylight saving time or not.

Answer (score -1):

```
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.now();
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTime(dateTime.toDate());
System.out.println("Current Timestamp:" + new Timestamp(calendar.getTimeInMillis()));
LocalDateTime localdateTime = LocalDateTime.parse("2014030902101100",
DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyyMMddHHmmssSS"));
System.out.println("Converted Timestamp:" + Timestamp.valueOf(localdateTime.toString("yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss")));
```

Comment: Why are you mixing Joda-Time with java.util.Date/Calendar?

Comment: To insert timestamp using simple JDBC code, i converted Joda-Time to java.sql.timestamp.